# Array params type based in the first position of array

Tags: typescript

I want to have diferent types of Modules and create it with array. In the first position we have the type of this module, and in the second position we have the params. I want to the params type based in the first position of array.

I tried this and examples:

```
type TextProps = {
    text: string
}
type TestProps = {
    test: string
}
export type AllowedModules = {
    text: TextProps
    test: TestProps
}
export type KeyModule = keyof AllowedModules
export type Module = [module: KeyModule, params: AllowedModules[KeyModule]]
```

Example 1 (incorrect): If i pass test the valid params are TestParams

```
const Module: Module = ['test', {text: 'asd'}]
```

Example 2 (correct):

```
const Module: Module = ['text', {text: 'asd'}]
```

My problem now is I can pass params from other types.

Edit:

Also I tried

`export type Module<T extends KeyModule> = [module: T, params: AllowedModules[T]]`

It is still wrong because if I do the following there is no errors

```
export type MyTest = {
    elements: Module<KeyModule>[]
}
const myTest: MyTest = {
    elements: [
        ['text', {test: 'asd'}]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have a generic type:

```
export type Module<T extends KeyModule> = [module: T, params: AllowedModules[T]]

const _module1: Module<'test'> = ['test', {text: 'x'}]
```

Comment: Also I found a problem in this answer you can look edit

Answer (score 0):

The most closest answer I found is:

```
type TextModule = [type: 'text', props: TextProps]
type TestModule = [type: 'test', props: TestProps]
export type Module = TextModule | TestModule
```